# GWT JUnit Test - Is it possible to ignore same-origin policy

Tags: java, gwt, junit, same-origin-policy, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am trying to run an asynchronous test and need to send a request to my server, which has a REST-API. So my problem is that the tests are executed on the local machine, but this obviously violates the same origin policy and I get a RuntimeError if I try to run the GWTtestCase:

```
com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestPermissionException: The URL http://<url-to-my-rest-service> is invalid or violates the same-origin security restriction
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder.doSend(RequestBuilder.java:394)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder.send(RequestBuilder.java:242)
    ...
```

I know that I can run these tests manually, but with the latest updates of my browser (chromium), the GWT-Plugin was removed. So I don't know how to launch the tests in SuperDevMode.

#### Questions:

- **Is there a way to ignore the same-origin policy for the GWT JUnit Tests?**
- **Can I change the browser which is used for the test to Chrome/Chromium?**
- **How can I manually run the tests with SuperDevMode in a browser?**

---

**Edit:**

If I want to run the tests manually I write the following into the terminal:

```
mvn gwt:test -Dgwt.args="-prod -userAgents safari -runStyle Manual:1"
```

Maven then will print an URL to the terminal which I should enter into the browser to execute the tests:

```
http://127.0.1.1:57818/<my-package>.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.1.1:40387
```

But if I enter this URL into my browser (Chromium) it will notify me that the GWT-Plugin is currently not installed. If I remove the part behind the question mark (like I do if I want to run the GWT-Code in SuperDevMode on the localhost) `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.1.1:40387` then the browser will show only a blank page, and also if I started the codeserver with:

```
mvn process-classes gwt:run-codeserver
```

the codeserver-bookmarks (`Dev Mode On`) are not working and GWT is not able to detect a module which is "compilable".

#### Question:

**So how excatly do I compile the JUnit-Test-Module with the SuperDevMode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bypass the SOP, but you could use a servlet to proxy requests to your remote server (servlets declared with `<servlet>` in your gwt.xml files are honored by JUnitShell).

And if you want to run the tests in Chrome/Chromium, you can either use `-runStyle Manual` or [Selenium](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTestingRemoteTesting.html#Selenium) (note: there's even a [custom run style for PhantomJS](https://github.com/neothemachine/gwt-phantomjs-junit-runstyle)), and because DevMode no longer works, as you noted, you'd have to run tests in prod mode: `-prod -userAgents safari`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try to run the tests manually in production mode in an external browser. But I have still two more questions:

I think the test should also fail on a servlet, because the servlet is still deployed on the localhost, but the REST-API server is not - right?

Don't I need to run the codeserver manually for the prdouction mode - like when I run the GWT code on localhost in SuperDevMode?